# Is it possible convert 3 shapefiles to 1 GPX file?

Tags: shapefile, ogr, ogr2ogr, gpx

I ran into problem converting shapefiles to a GPX file.

I used below code using ogr2ogr.

```
ogr2ogr -f gpx i.gpx i.shp
```

it works well, but I'd like to convert three shapefiles to one GPX file like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f gpx i.gpx **tracks.shp track_points.shp waypoints.shp**
```

[image]

is it possible? or should I use there other program?

Answer (score 3):

I fear it is at least quite difficult task with shapefiles. As documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpx.html it is possible to combine several layers from a datasource into gpx. The example is using gpx as input and outputformat

```
ogr2ogr -f GPX output.gpx input.gpx waypoints routes tracks
```

but as well the source could be some other format

```
ogr2ogr -f GPX output.gpx input.gpkg tracks track_points waypoints
```

You can make a single datasource from your three shapefiles by placing them all into a same directory, for example "gpxdir". Ogrinfo confirms that the layers are there

```
ogrinfo gpxdir
INFO: Open of `gpxdir'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: tracks (Line String)
2: track_points (Point)
3: waypoints (Point)
```

In theory the following should now work

```
ogr2ogr -f gpx i.gpx gpxdir tracks track_points waypoints
```

However, because of the limitations of the shapefile format it does not work. The input data for GPX must be valid according to the GPX schema, but it is impossible to have attribute names like `track_seg_point_id`in a shapefile because the name can have only 10 characters at maximum. Therefore the trial fails

```
ogr2ogr -f gpx i.gpx gpx.gpkg tracks track_points waypoints

ogr2ogr -f gpx i.gpx gpxdir tracks track_points waypoints
ERROR 6: Field of name 'track_seg_' is not supported in GPX schema. Use GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS creation option to allow use of the <extensions> element.
ERROR 6: Field of name 'track_se_1' is not supported in GPX schema. Use GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS creation option to allow use of the <extensions> element.
ERROR 6: Field of name 'geoidheigh' is not supported in GPX schema. Use GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS creation option to allow use of the <extensions> element.
ERROR 6: Field of name 'ageofdgpsd' is not supported in GPX schema. Use GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS creation option to allow use of the <extensions> element.
ERROR 1: Field track_seg_id must be set.
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 0 from layer track_points.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer track_points (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

With some better format than shapefile the original GPX data is preserved better and it is also possible to combine the data back.

Test with a GeoPackage did succeed

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg gpx.gpkg test.gpx
ogr2ogr -f gpx i.gpx gpx.gpkg tracks track_points waypoints
```

If the only problem with shapefiles is with the attribute names it could be possible to save the shapefiles into another format and rename the attributes but there may be other issues as well at least with long strings and datetimes.

Comment: you are genius !! thanks !! now I can deal with problems !